# Excel VBA: using R1C1 format, "Application defined or object defined error"

Tags: date, excel, offset, vba

I am trying to create a formula that references other cells, but I keep getting this "Application defined or object defined error". I use R1C1 convention instead of Offset.

My Code:

*Note: This code could be anywhere, I just need it to work. Also, I don't use the code like this. It is used in a reporting tool, but this is just similar code (to what I actually use) sufficient enough to show my problem*

```
Cells(1, 1).Value = "5/1/2014 6:30"
soiDate = "$A$1"
Cells(10, 6).Value = "6/5/2014 14:12"
Cells(10, 10).Formula = "=(R[0]C[-4]-" & soiDate & ")*24" 'Error Occurs Here
```

**UPDATE:**

The following does not work either:

```
Cells(10, 10).FormulaR1C1 = "=(R[0]C[-4]-" & soiDate & ")*24"
```

Comment: @pnuts I still need to be able to use a variable instead of `R[-9]C[-9]` for `soiDate` though. I tried using the same code that I posted, with `.Formula` changed to `FormulaR1C1`, and I still get the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Cells(10, 10).FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=(R[0]C[-4]-" & Range(soiDate).Address(, , xlR1C1) & ")*24"
```

It errors out since you kinda mixed up R1C1 reference to A1.
Just be consistent, you can use *Range Object* address property to convert reference. HTH.